# hibernate.jpa.criteria.BasicPathUsageException: Cannot join to attribute of basic type

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have two tables: `Tax` and `TaxRule`. There is one column same in both table i.e `TAX_RULE_ID`. But don't have any Hibernate mapping like `OneToOne` or `OneToMany`. Both table looks like-

**TAX**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "TAX_RATE_ID")
private Long taxRateId;

@Column(name = "TAX_RULE_ID")
private Long taxRuleId;

@Column(name = "TAX_TYPE")
private String taxType;
```

**TAX_RULE**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "TAX_RULE_ID")
private Long taxRuleId;

@Column(name = "TAX_CD")
private String TaxCode;

@Column(name = "STATE")
private String state;
```

I am trying to fetch data on the key i.e `TAX_RULE_ID`. This column is common in both table.
I have following `Hibernate` code in which I am joining both table on the `TAX_RULE_ID` column as follows:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String[]> cQuery =        criteriaBuilder.createQuery(String[].class);
Root<Tax> taxRoot = cQuery.from(Tax.class);

cQuery.multiselect(taxRateRoot.get("taxType"), taxRateRoot.get("taxRate"));
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
Join<Tax, TaxRule> join = taxRoot.join("taxRuleId"); 
.....rest of the code.
```

I am getting following Exception on the join point:

```
org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.BasicPathUsageException: Cannot join to attribute of basic type
at   org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.constructJoin(AbstractFromImpl.java:270)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.join(AbstractFromImpl.java:263)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractFromImpl.join(AbstractFromImpl.java:436)
at com.iclsystems.base.dao.TaxRateDAOImpl.getTaxTypeForApplicableWorkOrderTax(TaxRateDAOImpl.java:31)
at com.iclsystems.base.businessObjects.TaxLookupBOImpl.getTaxTypeForApplicableWorkOrderTax(TaxLookupBOImpl.java:53)
at com.iclsystems.base.businessObjects.TaxLookupBOImpl.getWorkOrderTaxLookup(TaxLookupBOImpl.java:29)
at com.iclsystems.test.eventhandler.base.TaxLookupBOTest.testTaxLookupBO(TaxLookupBOTest.java:52)
```

Comment: as the message says, you cannot join on a non-relation field. There is no relation in "taxRuleId".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot use the `@Join` annotation for a basic property (e.g., an attribute with a simple `@Column` mapping). `@Join` is for associations:

- one-to-one
- one-to-many
- many-to-one
- many-to-many

You need to remove this line, as the `taxRuleId` is already fetched from the database:

```
Join<Tax, TaxRule> join = taxRoot.join("taxRuleId");
```

If you want to join the TaxRule table, you need to replace the:

```
@Column(name = "TAX_RULE_ID")
private Long taxRuleId;
```

with a many-to-one association:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TAX_RULE_ID")
private TaxRule raxRule;
```

Comment: And what if you cannot alter TAX by adding the many-to-one association? Is it possible to do the join? I only ask because my entities are already fixed.

Comment: is it possible to filter out rows from the child table but fetch using the parent table this way?

Comment: If you fetch the child entities using a query, anything is possible. If you try to filter the collection while join fetching it, it will not be possible.